# cxf client in applet cause many repeating loading jars

Tags: applet, cxf

I have a web app with the applet to visit the cxf ws server.
When I init the the connection to the cxf ws,there are so many dirty messages(about 1000 lines,and cost about 2 minutes to init) such as:

```
network: Connecting \http://localhost:8080/WebUI/DYVCenterVNCClient.jar with proxy=DIRECT 
network: Connecting \http://localhost:8080/WebUI/DYVCenterVNCClient.jar and cookie "JSESSIONID=F7DF490E4E7137857494B453667A079E"
network: Connecting \http://localhost:8080/WebUI/DYVCenterVNCClient.jar with proxy=DIRECT 
network: Connecting \http://localhost:8080/WebUI/DYVCenterVNCClient.jar and cookie "JSESSIONID=F7DF490E4E7137857494B453667A079E"
```

the html applet config is:

```xml
<object type="application/x-java-applet"
        name="TestApplet" width="446" height="291">
    <param name="codebase" value="." />
    <param name="code" value="com.vnc.CompatibilityApplet" />
    <param name="archive" value="DYVCenterVNCClient.jar" />
    <PARAM NAME="cache_archive" VALUE="DYVCenterVNCClient.jar">
    <PARAM NAME="cache_version" VALUE="0.0.0.1">
    <PARAM name="codebase_lookup" value="false">
    <param name="scriptable" value="true" />
    <param name="mayscript" value="true" />
    <param name="background-color" value="#ffffff" />
    <param name="border-color" value="#8c8cad" />
</object>
```

and I found those message being printed out when call the cxf class ClientProxyFactoryBean's method create().

so how can I solve those problem,I also googing and found the similar problem with link:
http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/CXF-based-applet-initialization-worries-td550944.html
but there is no answers

thanks everyone.

Comment: I donnot want to use the jnlp method for the ugly downloading the jnlp file explicit

Comment: It's not downloading CXF over and over, it's downloading you. I doubt that has anything to do with CXF. And that email message is *ancient*. You could try the CXF user list.

Comment: And I using the param <PARAM name="codebase_lookup" value="false">
to aviod log some request to the properties files,such as `http://localhost:8080/WebUI/org/apache/cxf/common/logging/Messages.properties  `

Comment: when split DYVCenterVNCClient.jar into small jars, the main jar depending on the other jar such as the cxf jar.I found that the repeated request jars are most on the ConnInterface.jar and cxf-2.4.1.jar when call the ClientProxyFactoryBean's create() method.the log below:` network: Connecting \http://localhost:8080/WebUI/cxf-2.4.1.jar with proxy=DIRECT network: Connecting \http://localhost:8080/WebUI/cxf-2.4.1.jar with proxy=DIRECT 
network: Connecting \http://localhost:8080/WebUI/ConnInterface.jar with proxy=DIRECT 
`  Well ConnInterface.jar is the interface of the ws service.

Comment: This is some sort of classloading problem, but I'm not qualified to sort it out. List I said, the CXF user list.

Answer (score 0):

Well,at last I found this url
[Applet downloading server copy of jars already cached](http://www.coderanch.com/t/259275/Applets/java/Applet-downloading-server-copy-jars) tell us that the `URLConnection`'s `defaultUsecaches` is been updated with false.
So even if the plugin itself is set to "use cache", the `urlconnection` will not use the cache.

I search the method `setDefaultUseCaches(false)` in cxf src ,at last I found that the JDKBugHacks's method `doHacks()` will set the defaultUseCache to false.And seems that the jdk's bug which confuse me.

finally I solve my problem with change the defaultUsecaches after the new `ClientProxyFactoryBean`.

```
try{  
   URL url = new URL("any valid url is ok");  
   URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
   urlConnection.setDefaultUseCaches(true);  
}catch(Exception e){  
   //;
}
```